# Program received signal sigsegv segmentation fault

Tags: c, ponteiro, matriz

Fiz o código em C do enunciado:

> Elabore um programa que simule um sistema de emissão de bilhetes de uma
>   companhia aérea. A companhia possui n vôos, onde em cada um deles existem m
>   lugares disponíveis. Os primeiros m/2 lugares de cada vôo estão reservados para não fumantes e o restante para fumantes.
>
> Utilize uma matriz de n linhas por m colunas para representar os assentos dos vôos desta companhia. Inicialize os elementos da matriz com zero para indicar que todos os assentos de cada um dos n vôos estão disponíveis. À medida que os assentos forem sendo ocupados atribua 1 ao elemento correspondente da matriz.
>
> Devem ser gerados aleatoriamente:
>
> 1. O número de vôos.
> 2. O número de passagens solicitadas por vôo.
> 3. Se o passageiro é da área dos fumantes ou dos não fumantes.
>      O programa devera imprimir no final da simulação:
> 4. O número médio de passageiros por vôo.
> 5. O número médio de passageiros por área em cada vôo
> 6. O Número médio de passageiros não embarcados por falta de assento (observe
>      que pode haver lugar no avião, mas não haver lugar na área solicitada)

Já usei o debug mas não consigo identificar o motivo do erro: Program received signal sigsegv segmentation fault Já mudei e coloquei de diversas formas o iniciar gerador de numeros aleatórios, usando NULL por exemplo, mas não adianta. srand(time(NULL)), abaixo o código:

```
main() {


  int n,m,p, i, j, matriz[n][m],f,assento_ocup,aux,fumantes,nao_fumantes; 
  float media_passageiros_voo, media_passageiros_area,media_pas_falta_assento,
  media_passageiros_nao_fumantes_area, media_passageiros_fumantes_area;
  time_t t;


  // iniciar gerador de numeros aleatórios
  srand((unsigned)time(&t));

  //numero de voos-linhas
  n=rand()%1+500;

  //numero de lugares-colunas
  m= rand()%1+100;

  //numero de passagens solicitadas
  p= rand()%1+100;


  for(i=0; i<n; i++)  { //linha-voos
    for(j=0; j<m; j++){//coluna-passagens
        matriz[n][m]=0;//todos assentos disponiveis
    }
  }

  if(f%2==0){//se par nao e fumante
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)  { 
        for(j=0; j<m/2; j++){
              matriz[i][j]=1;
              nao_fumantes++;
            }
    }
  }
  else{ //e fumante
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)  { 
        aux=((m/2)+1);
        for(j=aux; j<m; j++){
            matriz[i][j]=1;
            fumantes++;
        }
    }   
  }

  for(i=0; i<n; i++)  { 
    for(j=0; j<m; j++){
        if(matriz[i][j]==1){
            assento_ocup++;
        }
    }
  }

  media_passageiros_voo=assento_ocup/n;

  media_pas_falta_assento= m-p;

  media_passageiros_fumantes_area= fumantes/(m/2);
  media_passageiros_nao_fumantes_area= nao_fumantes/(m/2);

  printf("\n MEDIA DE PASSAGEIROS POR VOO:%.2f ",media_passageiros_voo);
  printf("\n MEDIA DE PASSAGEIROS POR AREA EM CADA VOO: %.2f", media_passageiros_area);  
  printf("\n PASSAGEIROS NAO EMBARCADOS POR FALTA DE ASSENTO",media_pas_falta_assento);

  getche();

}
```

Comment: O `gdb` (debugger) pode te dar ao menos uma noção de onde o SegFault está acontecendo. Experimente o comando `backtrace` logo após o erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiramente, não se usa variáveis em declarações de tamanhos de *arrays*, ainda mais antes mesmo de defini-las, como você fez em `matriz[n][m]`. Coloque números inteiros como tamanhos ou defina suas próprias constantes com `#define` e faça algo do tipo

```
matriz[LINHAS_MAX][COLUNAS_MAX]
```

E, claramente, a seguinte linha está errada (provavelmente por erro de digitação):

```
matriz[n][m]=0;//todos assentos disponiveis
```

Deveria ser `matriz[i][j]` no lugar.

Comment: Tens razão, utilizei o #define e deu certo .. 
e sim, tinha esse erro de digitação.
Obrigada

Comment: Você pode usar variáveis para declarar tamanho de vetores e matrizes. A matriz terá uma alocação automática e seu espaço será liberado tão logo saia de seu escopo de variável. Mais sobre o assunto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/281116/64969