# Variáveis declaradas dentro de blocos ou subprogramas são alocadas dinamicamente?

Tags: c, alocação, declaração-de-variável, stack, heap

Estou lendo o livro "Algoritmos e Programação com Exemplos em Pascal e C" e nele há dois parágrafos que me deixou na dúvida, são eles:

> Duas formas alternativas são oferecidas por algumas linguagens de programação para gerenciar a alocação dinâmica: (1) declaração de variáveis dentro de blocos (Capítulo 4) ou em subprogramas (Capítulo 9); e (2) alocação de espaço por meio de ponteiros.
>
> Na alocação dinâmica envolvendo variáveis declaradas dentro de blocos ou subprogramas, as variáveis armazenam valores da aplicação da mesma forma que as variáveis estáticas, mas elas são alocadas pelo sistema ao iniciar a execução do bloco ou subprograma e só persistem enquanto durar a execução do mesmo. As áreas de memória associadas a variáveis declaradas nessa modalidade são liberadas automaticamente pelo sistema.

Conforme a autora, a declaração de variáveis dentro de blocos ou em
subprogramas envolve alocação dinâmica. Esta correta esta afirmação? No meu entendimento, apenas a alocação por meio de ponteiros é considerada alocação dinâmica.

Comment: [Esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3797/o-que-s%C3%A3o-e-onde-est%C3%A3o-o-stack-e-heap) do @Maneiro responde a todas as suas questões. Não sei até que ponto não será duplicada mesmo

Comment: @Isac, o post que você se refere não responde a "todas" questões que fiz aqui. O meu questionamento está mais relacionado aos termos "alocação dinâmica" ou "alocação automática" do que propriamente o conceito de alocação na heap, stack, seguimento de código, seguimento de dados etc.

Comment: Se é esse o caso, parece-me que não deixou isso muito claro na pergunta.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 4):

O termo alocação dinâmica não costuma ser usado nesse contexto. De certa forma até é verdade. Esse tipo de alocação ocorre na [pilha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101), então ocorre sempre em tempo de execução, nesse aspecto podemos dizer que a alocação é dinâmica, em oposição a ser estática quando o dado já está no código binário e a alocação foi feita em tempo de compilação. Porém se pensar bem até esse dado não deixa de ser dinâmico porque a alocação efetiva só ocorre na carga do executável.

O termo caiu um pouco em desuso, mas o correto para a alocação na pilha é **alocação automática**, assim diferencia da estática. Em certo sentido a memória ali é estática já que toda a pilha costuma ter tamanho fixo e alocado antecipadamente. Então há uma alocação prévia geral na carga do executável e depois uma alocação interna durante a execução que cada *stack frame*.

Por tudo isso considera-se que essas alocações são sempre estáticas ou automáticas, e a alocação dinâmica é aquela que você pede para [alocar no *heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56580/101) e ela é acessada por valor ou através de um referência em algum lugar.

A alocação dinâmica precisa de algum gerenciamento enquanto que a alocação estática é gerenciada automaticamente. Esse gerenciamento pode ser automático através de um coletor de lixo ([*garbage collector*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/255769/101)) ou [manual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43766/101).

O termo "variáveis estáticas" é completamente errado. A alocação pode ter essa característica, uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) não.

A alocação dinâmica não precisa necessariamente ser através de ponteiros, mas quase sempre acaba sendo acessado assim. Mas de uma certa forma todo acesso é feito assim, é que alguns casos o endereço do ponteiro já está no código e provavelmente o processador torna o acesso sem custo ou até transparente. Tudo é feito com [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101).

Na memória automática nunca é liberado nada, apenas deixa-se de usar aquele espaço.

Portanto dentro do que se usa na nossa área a autora está errada, bem como as respostas postadas aqui (que inclusive erram em pontos que nem são o foco da pergunta). A autora fala de [escopo e tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101).

Comment: obrigado pelos esclarecimentos. De forma sucinta, acredito que o termo correto, neste caso, seria "alocação automática" visto que a alocação ocorre na stack e os recursos são liberados automaticamente ao fim da função ou bloco.

Comment: @RodrigoCosta A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 1):

Está correto, `Alocação Dinâmica` no contexto que é citado pela autora refere-se ao fato de que uma variável existente em um bloco de código, seja ele uma função, `for`, `while`, `if`, etc. Existe somente dentro daquele escopo de código. Ou seja, ela é criada quando aquele escopo é executado, e (possivelmente) ***liberada da memória quando sua execução termina***.

Análisando um exemplo básico:

```
function foo() {
   var a = 4; // existe no escopo de foo() e bar().

   function bar() {
      var b = 5; //existe no escopo de bar(), não existe no escopo de foo();
   }
 // var b não existe aqui..
}
// var a e b não existe aqui...
```