# Tamanho máximo de um vetor de caracteres

Tags: c, memória, char

Tem alguma quantidade máxima, que uma variável do tipo `char` suporta de caracteres?

Por exemplo, eu poderia usar `char texto[1000];`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(){

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("copyright.txt", "r");

    char pagina1[928];

    while(fgets(pagina1, 928, file) != NULL){
        printf("%s", &pagina1);
    }
    fclose(file);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não sei se entendi a pergunta, pode tentar deixar mais claro. Não vejo alguma dúvida, só afirmação ou obviedade (pra mim).

Comment: Minha dúvida, é se tem alguma quantidade máxima, que uma variável do tipo char suporta de caraceteres.

Comment: Pois o programa não está querendo ler o arquivo .txt

Comment: `printf("%s", &pagina1); ` tire esse  `&` daí - deixe só `printf("%s", pagina1); `

Comment: Leu normal corrigindo o ponteiro a ser exibido: https://repl.it/@acwoss/EarlyRashCustomer

Comment: Realmente o '&' botei sem querer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O tipo `char` tem sempre tamanho de 1 byte, e portanto um caractere, desde que seja uma codificação *single byte* (o `char` não suporte caracteres *multibyte*).

Uma sequência de `char` pode ter a quantidade máxima de bytes disponíveis no endereçamento permitido pelo sistema operacional e que esteja livre naquele momento, porém dependendo de onde esta sequência esteja alocada pode ser um problema.

No seu exemplo está alocando no *stack*, que em condições normais, dependendo do sistema operacional, tem 1 MB disponível apenas, para toda aplicação. Ela é uma memória bastante dinâmica (para minha tristeza muitos a consideram estática) e seu [gerenciamento é **automático**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/280973/101), então a parte usada efetivamente cresce e decresce frequentemente, mas não convém abusar, se for alocar vetores muitos grandes é melhor optar pelo *heap*, a não ser que saiba bem o que está fazendo ou entenda os truques para crescer o *stack* além do tamanho padrão, entendendo as consequências disto. 1KB ou menos não é para ser problema em um exemplo simples assim, poderia se tivesse uma chamada recursiva, ou tivesse outros componentes grandes na pilha de chamada.

No *heap* você pode alocar vários megabytes ou até gibabytes sem grandes problemas, mas se passar da quantidade disponível na memória RAM haverá o *swap* de memória e a aplicação ficará extremamente lenta, então contenha o uso, mas isso é um senso até óbvio. Em arquiteturas 32 bits o máximo endereçável costuma ser 2GB. Em 64 bits é virtualmente impossível chegar a estourar o endereçamento, mas pode estourar a RAM (tradicional, em breve teremos as memórias não voláteis persistentes de grande capacidade, aí é outra estória, muito do que aprendemos até hoje não valerá mais :) ).

Fora isto "o programa não querer ler o arquivo" é algo vago demais para podermos ajudar. Mas o código apresenta alguns problemas, e isto é que deve estar impedindo a execução normal.

Comment: Realmente o código estava com umas coisas aqui que resolvi e o programa rodou normalmente. Porém minha dúvida não era sobre o código e sim se o tipo char teria algum valor máximo de caracteres, pois eu estou fazendo um VT para a faculdade e pretendo fazer um programa parecendo um eBook, sendo que tem páginas com muitos caractéres e eu não sei, se o tipo char aguenta tudo isso. Muito obrigado pela explicação vou tentar dar uma pesquisada sobre Heap.

Comment: @PauloSergioG.M.Filho https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101 e pesquise mais no site que tem muita informação boa

Comment: Sim, sim, como sempre você me salvando e não é a primeira vez, muito obrigado de verdade.

Answer (score 4):

A resposta a essa pergunta não é tão óbvia, e entender o que acontece implica em entender o que você está fazendo.

Primeiro: uma variável do tipo "char" comporta **um único byte**, que para o alfabeto latino e dígitos arábicos, normalemente equivale a um único caractére - (mas isso depende da codificação usada.)

A variável que você está usando é um `char[]` - isso é um ponteiro de caracteres. O que vai "dentro" da variável em si é um endereço de memória, o que, em PCs normais é em geral um endereço de 8 bytes (64bit);
O número que vai entre os colchetes, como em `char minhavariavel[1000]`, é uma quantidade de bytes que o compilador deixa reservado na memória para a sua variável. O valor máximo depende da arquitetura da CPU (nos primeiros PC x86 de 16bit assim como nas máquinas 8 bits, esse número era 2^16 = 65536, por exemplo). O tamanho máximo para isso depende da estrutura do programa como é definido pelo compilador, e com o limite dado pelo sistema operacional - em PCs com sistemas modernos, pode-se pensar em torno de 1MB para isso. Acabei de testar aqui, 5MB funciona, 10MB, o programa falha, num Linux 64bit)

Num PC rodando um S.O. de 64 bit, esse número é limitado pelo compilador, por conta da estrutura que o mesmo usa para organizar o programa na memória, mas se a memória for solicitada do Sistema Operacional, em tempo de exercução, o tamanho de um vetor de `char` pode ser tão grande quando se queira, com o limite da memória do computador. (Nm PC com 4GB, você separa uns 300-400MB para o sistema operacional e programas que o mesmo usa, e poderia ter um processo usando 3.6GB sem suar muito. Se estiver manipulando arquivos de texto, como está, corresponde a grosso modo, ao texto equivalente a 1000 bíblias) -

Mas se você tem um programa que vai trabalhar com essa quantidade de dados na memória em geral vale a pena usar um mecanismo de alocação dinâmica de memória.

Em suma - não, não há um limite para a quantidade de bytes que você pode alocar para um vetor do tipo `char` , exceto a memória do seu computador.

E o erro que você está tendo de "não conseguir ler o arquivo", provavelmente está relacionado com o erro na chamada do `printf` como eu apontei no comentário é só tirar o `&` a mais.

Comment: Realmente, o '&' tinha colocado sem querer, a minha dúvida não era nem sobre o código em si, era pra saber se o tipo char armazenava um valor máximo de caracteres, mas consegui tirar minha dúvida com sua explicação, muito obrigado.

Comment: A resposta estava errada sobre a notação fixa no código fonte poder usar toda a memória do computador. Não pode devido a estrutura do executável gerada pelo compilador, mas cm alocação dnâmica chamando a função `malloc`, o limite realmente não existe.